# Pulling rows from 3x columns based off dates

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns of importance in my table, each of which store a date.

ID
Inpatient_date
ER_date

I am trying to find which people (ID) went to the ER (ER_date) within 30 days of seeing the hospital (Inpatient_date). I need to be able to look at every date within the inpatient_date column, and compare to every date in the ER_date column. Then from those results, further narrow it down by having the row with the ER_date that was within 30 days, and the row housing the Inpatient_date have the same persons ID.

I am at a loss on how to do this.

Comment: In case you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.er_date > t.inpatient_date and
                    t2.er_date < t.inpatient_date + interval 30 day
             );
```

I am interpreting your question as "visits the ER 1-30 days after being in the hospital".  If you are looking for 30 days before, or 30 days before and after, you can adjust the condition in the subquery.